# I can't login to Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: boot, 18.04

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 on a Raspberry pi. when I started it up it went straight to a LTS ubuntu tty1, login screen. I can't figure out how to login from here

I keep getting a "login incorrect" message

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the password wasn't supposed to be empty like I had been seeing. My password was "ubuntu"